# How does $-[-\pi]$ equal 4?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation, pi

For Christmas I got a math watch and for 4 it was $-[-\pi]$.  I know that $\pi$ does not equal 4 so how does $-[-\pi]$ equal 4?  Thank you.

Comment: The symbol $[ \cdot ]$ means to take the floor. It's not a general bracket. The floor of $-\pi$ is $-4$ (since it is the largest integer smaller than $-\pi$) and then taking the negative of it gives you $4$.

Comment: what do that $[.]$ stand for?

Comment: I think the $\cdot$ was meant as a place holder.  $\lfloor x \rfloor$ means the largest integer less than or equal to x.

Comment: Sounds like it should have just been $\lceil \pi \rceil$. That's gimmicky enough.

Comment: "should"? "gimmicky enough"? the *entire* point of the watch is to be convoluted so "$-\lfloor \pi \rfloor$ is *much better than ceiling pi because it's much less direct.

Comment: @fleablood "Should" in the sense that $[x]$ is not as "universal" as $\lfloor x\rfloor$. And to what extent it should be convoluted I guess is a matter of opinion.

Comment: I have a suspicion it *was* $\lfloor  \pi \rfloor$.  If it isn't supposed to be convoluted it'd say "4".  The entire point is something quasi-convoluted.

Comment: Cool watch.  I want a mathy watch that uses complex values from the unit circle on the complex plane to tell me time.  ;D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$[x]$ is the floor of $x$, the largest integer less than or equal to $x$. For example $[4.6]=4$, $[7]=7$ and $[-67.4]=-68$.

So $-[-\pi]=-(-4)=4$

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you! So is [x] just called the floor? or is there another name for it?

Comment: Isn't $[x]$ often the nearest integer?

Comment: @CuddlyCuttlefish Yes it can often be used in that context. The notation is unfortunately not very uniform.

Comment: @CuddlyCuttlefish The nearest integer to $n$ is $\lfloor n+0.5\rfloor$.

Comment: I think its ceiling function rather than floor

Comment: @ArchisWelankar That wouldn't make sense here.

Comment: @user236182: Not "the nearest integer to $n$", but rather "$n$ rounded up to the nearest integer". There is no such thing as "the nearest integer" since, for example, $0$ and $1$ are equally near to $\frac12$.

Comment: @MPW Numbers of the form $\overline{k.5}$ with $k$ integer is the only exception where "the nearest integer" depends on your convention. In all other cases "nearest integer" is unambiguous and given by $\lfloor n+0.5\rfloor$. I should've mentioned that. There's a [Wikipedia page on "nearest integer"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_integer_function).

Comment: @user236182: I understand. My point is that there are lots of rounding rules to handle the problematic points. Round up, round down, round up or down according to whether the $1+ \lfloor |n|\rfloor$th decimal digit of $\pi$ is odd or even...

Answer (score 1):

Well... $[ x ]$ gives the largest integer $\leq x$. That is, $[ x ] = \sup\{z : z \in \mathbb{Z}, z\leq x\}$ if one likes to complicate things. Anyway, it's rather straightforward to prove your claim:
$$- [ - \pi ] = - [ -3.1415\ldots\, ] = - (-4) = 4$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** By definition, $x=[x]+\{x\}.$ By convention, $\{x\}\ge0$.